# ListView inside of LinearLayout won't grow to show all children

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I'm building up a sliding menu which opens from the side. In the menu, there is a `ScrollView` with a `LinearLayout` inside it for general layout and scrolling. Plus, for displaying the menu items, I have a list view inside the `LinearLayout`, meaning that the view hierarchy goes like:

```
ScrollView
    LinearLayout
        ListView
```

I'm trying to populate the `ListView` with a custom adapter, which gets its data from an array. But surprisingly when I populate the data, the `ListView` doesn't grow to show all of its children, even with being set to `wrap_content`. Instead it just displays one item, but I'm able to scroll over that item to see the rest of the items.

I'm guessing it's because it is already in a `ScrollView`, but I don't want the scroll functionality of the `ListView`. I just want it do display all the menu items, and let the `ScrollView` take care of the scrolling. The menu items won't grow over 10, so I'm not worried about memory usage right now.

Is there a way, possibly by extending the `ListView`, to disable the scrolling and make it really do `wrap_content`?

Layout XML:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#2e2e2e">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/menu_profile_picture"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/default_profile_picture"
            app:border_color="#FFF"
            app:border_width="2dp"/>

        <com.devspark.robototextview.widget.RobotoTextView
            android:id="@+id/menu_user_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="John Doe"
            android:textColor="#FFF"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            app:typeface="roboto_thin"/>


        <com.devspark.robototextview.widget.RobotoTextView
            android:id="@+id/menu_logged_in"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="LOGGED IN"
            android:textColor="#1e4472"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            app:typeface="roboto_light"/>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/menu_items"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/menu_logout_icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_logout"/>

        <com.devspark.robototextview.widget.RobotoTextView
            android:id="@+id/menu_logout_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="LOG OUT"
            android:textColor="#e20202"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            app:typeface="roboto_light"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Please, sharing with us your code or your xml.

Comment: @user3586222: Code added!

Comment: First, use this, http://pastebin.com/Ep5nivsM, to comprobate if your adapter is wrong or your xml.

Comment: THe golden rule is not to put a `View` with scrolling ability into another. If you don't want the scrolling functionality of `ListView` then you'd be better off using something like a `TableLayout` instead of `ListView` and dynamically add `TableRows`.

Comment: Thanks @Squonk. I fixed it with `TableLayout`. If you put your comment as an answer, I'd be happy to accept it.

Comment: @MiroMarkarian : Glad I was able to help. Answer added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One golden rule is not to put a View with scrolling ability into another.

If you don't want the scrolling functionality of `ListView` then you'd be better off using something like a `TableLayout` instead of `ListView` and dynamically add `TableRows`.